# ngx-extended-pdf-viewer not working with Url

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf.js, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I cannot get my pdf to display on viewer via url in typescript. I am using  ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Here is an example of my code with the URL replaced.

```
<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer 
*ngIf="!isFirefox"  
  [src]="'http://www.childrensbooksforever.com/Childrenpics/A%20COOL%20KID%20LIKE%20ME.pdf'"
  useBrowserLocale="true" 
  backgroundColor="#000000" 
  height="100%">            
</ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
```

Error message in the viewer:

```
PDF.js v2.1.266 (build: 81f5835c)
Message: Failed to fetch
```

in the pdf viewer.

I can view the pdf if i place it in the assets folder but the url doesn't work. 
An empty frame is shown. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: the errors are quite self-explanatory buddy. The 1st error says that the object whose property `clientHeight` you're referring to is undefined. And regarding the second, [this gitHub discussion](https://github.com/stephanrauh/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/issues/20) might help you.

Comment: This seems to be the same issue as https://github.com/stephanrauh/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/issues/98.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, but my most likely explanation is "CORS". Modern browsers protect you against a certain class of hacker attacks by refusing to download or send stuff from another URL.

You've mentioned accessing local file works, so chances are using a proxy will fix the problem. For example, there's the proxy-conf.json in the Angular CLI.

Comment: One question about this one, say you have the pdf viewer embedded inside the iframe and iframe and parent window are from different origins, would the browser allow download functionality?